# how to pivot a table represented as scala List of Maps by taking one column and converting it to row?

Tags: scala

I have following table data represented as scala's List[Map[String, Any]]

[image: inputData]

Following is scala code for creating such list of map

```
val inputData = List(
    Map(
    "d1_name" -> "t1",
    "d1_id" -> 1,
    "d2_name" -> "p1",
    "d2_id" -> 11,
    "value1" -> 5,
    "value2" -> 12,
    "value3" -> 30
    ),
    Map(
    "d1_name" -> "t1",
    "d1_id" -> 1,
    "d2_name" -> "p2",
    "d2_id" -> 22,
    "value1" -> 10,
    "value2" -> 14,
    "value3" -> 300
    ),
    Map(
    "d1_name" -> "t2",
    "d1_id" -> 2,
    "d2_name" -> "p3",
    "d2_id" -> 33,
    "value1" -> 15,
    "value2" -> 16,
    "value3" -> 33
    ),
    Map(
    "d1_name" -> "t3",
    "d1_id" -> 3,
    "d2_name" -> "p7",
    "d2_id" -> 7,
    "value1" -> 5,
    "value2" -> 8,
    "value3" -> 17
    )
)
```

I want to convert shown input table to following pivoted output table in scala, the operation is to pivot "`d1_name`" column over `value3` data, also dropping "`d1_id`" column in final output.

(i am expecting same `List[Map[String, Any]]` output type)

following is pictorial representation of output.

[image: output table]

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

Use `GroupBy` with the column `d1_name` and for each element in the grouped list get modify data as required.

```
  inputData.groupBy(_.getOrElse("d1_name", "")).flatMap(e => {
e._2.map(list => {
   Map(
      "d2_name" -> list.getOrElse("d2_name", ""),
      "d2_id" -> list.getOrElse("d2_id", ""),
      "value1" -> list.getOrElse("value1", 0),
      "value2" -> list.getOrElse("value2", 0),
      "value3" -> list.getOrElse("value3", 0),
     if (e._1 == "t1") {"t1-value3" -> list.getOrElse("value3", 0)} else {"t1-value3" -> 0},
     if (e._1 == "t2") {"t2-value3" -> list.getOrElse("value3", 0)} else {"t2-value3" -> 0},
     if (e._1 == "t3") {"t3-value3" -> list.getOrElse("value3", 0)} else {"t3-value3" -> 0}
   )
  }
  )
})
//   List(
    Map(value3 -> 30, t3-value3 -> 0, t2-value3 -> 0, d2_name -> p1, value1 -> 5, t1-value3 -> 30, value2 -> 12, d2_id -> 11), 
    Map(value3 -> 300, t3-value3 -> 0, t2-value3 -> 0, d2_name -> p2, value1 -> 10, t1-value3 -> 300, value2 -> 14, d2_id -> 22), 
    Map(value3 -> 17, t3-value3 -> 17, t2-value3 -> 0, d2_name -> p7, value1 -> 5, t1-value3 -> 0, value2 -> 8, d2_id -> 7), 
    Map(value3 -> 33, t3-value3 -> 0, t2-value3 -> 33, d2_name -> p3, value1 -> 15, t1-value3 -> 0, value2 -> 16, d2_id -> 33)
 )
```

Hope this helps you.

**---EDIT----**

To generate the keys dynamically

```
val groupedInput = inputData.groupBy(_.getOrElse("d1_name", ""))
val uniqueKeys = groupedInput.keySet
groupedInput.flatMap(e => {
e._2.map(list => {
  val value3= uniqueKeys.map(key => if (e._1 == key) {key+"-value3" -> list.getOrElse("value3", 0)} else {key+"-value3" -> 0})
   Map(
      List("d2_name" -> list.getOrElse("d2_name", ""),
      "d2_id" -> list.getOrElse("d2_id", ""),
      "value1" -> list.getOrElse("value1", 0),
      "value2" -> list.getOrElse("value2", 0),
      "value3" -> list.getOrElse("value3", 0)).++(value3) :_*
   )
  }
  )
})
```

Comment: Puneeth as data is coming from DB, "t1", "t2" will be dynamic and not static, so i can't always compare like e._1=="t1"

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: This code re-orders the rows, which may or may not be important.

Answer (score 1):

This version pivots `"value3"` based on the value of `"d1_name"`, and deletes `"d1_id"`. It leaves other values untouched. In a proper implementation these would be taken out as parameters, and there would be more error checking.

```
val defaults = // Compute default "table" for new pivot values
  inputData
    .map(_("d1_name").toString + "-" + "value3" -> 0)
    .toMap

val pivot = // Add new pivot values to existing "table"
  inputData.map { map =>
    val d1Name = map("d1_name") + "-" + "value3"

    map ++ defaults + (d1Name -> map("value3")) - "d1_name" - "d1_id"
  }
```